# WPF DataGrid ComboBox SelectedItem Property Setter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I am looking for an example of how to use the SelectedItem property inside a combobox in a WPF DataGrid, I have

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        SelectedValuePath="CID"  
                        Header="CID" 
                        Width="70">
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ListCustomerCollection, 
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>
                <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding DataContext.Customer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"></Setter> 
            </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DataContext.ListCustomerCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Name"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding DataContext.Customer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
```

The DataContext I bind to (ListCustomerCollection) is a List object

```
  List<Customer>
```

so the property in the ViewModel property I have set is

```
private Customer m_Customer = null;
public Customer Customer
{
    get { return m_Customer; }
    set
    {
        m_Customer = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Customer");
    }
}
```

So how do I writethe XAML to set the above property with the SelectedItem?

Comment: Do you have the `SelectedValue`, `SelectedItem`, or `SelectedIndex` property set? `DisplayMemberPath` only sets the value used for displaying the items in the combobox, and isn't used for the Selected Item

Comment: Hi Rachel, I will post all of the XAML above, thanks

Comment: And it owuld be the SelectedItem, however, as this is causing problems, I wouldnt mind taking the SelectedValue of the combo when selected, I just need the the value back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If property resides in window's ViewModel, you have to get window's DataContext like you did for ItemsSource.

```
<Setter Property="SelectedItem"
        Value="{Binding DataContext.Customer,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                 AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: Hi Rohit, the property now gets set, thanks, but the values do not show in the combobox no more, ( an error appears) I have posted the rest of the XAML above as I gather other code in there maybe causing the issue

Comment: If you already have `SelectedValueBinding` why you need `SelectedItem` as well?

Comment: Actually, you have solved it, I have put the above code in the EditingElementStyle tag and bingo! I get what you mean, but I cant access the SelectedValueBinding in the ViewModel, how  would I do this?

Comment: Actually the problem is you can't bind `SelectedValue` and `SelectedItem` to two completely different properties. `CID` property resides in model then any code you need to should be there in model. Why your ViewModel need to know about it? In case you still need it, somehow you have to get DataGrid selected row and get its Model from which you can get the `CID` value.