# ComboBox SelectedItem property updating all other comboboxes in my Datagrid row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have seen a couple of posts in this site similar to my issue like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091221/wpf-datagrid-combobox-selecteditem-property-setter) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261468/why-changing-selecteditem-in-one-combo-changes-all-other-combos) But I haven't gotten this to work for me.

I have a **datagrid** bound to by a list of objects of type *Foo* and I have a **combobox** added for each row. The **ComboBox** *ItemSource* is not a part of the *Foo* class but rather it's created in the view model. I know doing so means that this combobox is the same for every row but isn't there a way in my Xaml to filter SelectedItem to just the row?

Here is my Xaml:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Foo Column" Width="100">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay,Path=DataContext.FooCollection,       
     RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
      AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                        SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedComboBoxItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,       
     RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor,
      AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}">
                                    </ComboBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> FooCollection
            {
                get
                {
                    return _FooCollection;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_FooCollection != value)
                    {
                        _FooCollection = value;
                        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(FooCollection));
                    }
                }
            }
            private ObservableCollection<string> _FooCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            public string SelectedComboBoxItem
            {
                get
                {
                    return __SelectedComboBoxItem;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (_SelectedComboBoxItem != value)
                    {
                        _SelectedComboBoxItem = value;

                        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedComboBoxItem));
                    }
                }
            }
            private string _SelectedComboBoxItem = string.Empty;
```

I am seeing my combobox collection populated but when I make a selection every other combobox gets the same value. Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the ViewModel. It seems that all the comboboxes of datagrid is bound to `SelectedComboBoxItem`. What it should bind to a `property of item` of collection which is bind to `DataGrid`

Comment: @user1672994 can do

Comment: The `SelectedComboBoxItem` should part of `FooCollection`. Change the property to `public ObservableCollection<MyType> FooCollection` which should define the additional property `SelectedComboBoxItem` and later change the binding to `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboBoxItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}`

Comment: `FooCollection` is bound to every combobox, adding `SelectedComboBoxItem` to this collection didn't solve the problem. @user2529011 Can you share the complete xaml for `DataGrid`? `SelectedComboBoxItem` should be the part of `Foo` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code working you'll need to bind the `SelectedComboBoxItem` to `DataGrid` item. In your case this is a `Foo` type

> I have a datagrid bound to by a list of objects of type Foo

Place this code to `Foo` class

```cs
public string SelectedComboBoxItem
{
    get
    {
        return __SelectedComboBoxItem;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_SelectedComboBoxItem != value)
        {
            _SelectedComboBoxItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedComboBoxItem));
        }
    }
}

private string _SelectedComboBoxItem = string.Empty;
```

and update your binding according that

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboBoxItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```